# SQL LEFT JOIN with additional condition added to ON

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
table: users
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | alpha |
|  2 | beta  |
|  3 | gamma |
+----+-------+

table: address
+----+---------+------+--------------+
| id | user_id | type |   address    |
+----+---------+------+--------------+
|  1 |       1 | PRA  | welcome      |
|  2 |       1 | COA  | to the hotel |
|  3 |       2 | PRA  | california   |
+----+---------+------+--------------+
```

I understand the result of this query:

```
select u.*, a.*
from ccr.SJ_TEMP_USERS u
LEFT JOIN SJ_TEMP_ADDRESS a
on u.id = a.USER_ID
WHERE a.id IS NULL;
+----+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| ID | NAME  |  ID_1  | USER_ID |  TYPE  | ADDRESS |
+----+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
|  3 | gamma | (null) | (null)  | (null) | (null)  |
+----+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

But I don't understand the result of this query.

```
select u.*, a.*
from ccr.SJ_TEMP_USERS u
LEFT JOIN SJ_TEMP_ADDRESS a
on u.id = a.USER_ID
and a.type = 'COA'
WHERE a.id IS NULL;

+----+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| ID | NAME  |  ID_1  | USER_ID |  TYPE  | ADDRESS |
+----+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
|  3 | gamma | (null) | (null)  | (null) | (null)  |
|  2 | beta  | (null) | (null)  | (null) | (null)  |
+----+-------+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

Please help me understand why do I get the row with 'beta' in the second query.
(I'm using Oracle SQL Developer).

Note that the row with 'alpha' does not appear if I put the condition `a.type = 'PRA'` instead of `a.type = 'COA'`

Comment: `beta` Has an `address` on `user_id`, so it is not returned in your first query. `beta` Does not have an `address` based on `user_id` AND `type = 'COA'`, therefor it is returned in your second query.

Comment: Ah! got it, thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `where` clause takes place after the joining. The `on` clause is applied to the join itself, so the extra addition `a.type = 'COA'` to the `on` clause, will exclude more addresses, while leaving the results from the users table unaffected (until you start filtering using the where clause).

More concretely:

In the first query, you say "Give me all rows, for which there is no matching address (at all)." This is only true for Gamma, since there is no address with user_id 3.

In the second query, you say "Give me all rows, for which there is no matching address of the type "COA", which is true for Gamma and Beta, because the address of Beta is of a different type.

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is retrieving the unmatched records from the these two tables. ie when you say

```
u.id = a.USER_ID and a.type = 'COA'
```

from `SJ_TEMP_ADDRESS` table it is matching with only one record and

```
WHERE a.id IS NULL
```

gives unmatched records from  `SJ_TEMP_ADDRESS` table.
Same thing  happens when you give condition `a.type = 'PRA'` ,since there is type of alpha is `pra` it is matching in second table and you will get only beta record